# Secure Erase for IOS

Tags: data-recovery

The topics about secure erase for IOS on this site is a bit dated. Technology has definitely changed, including the tools used for forensics. Are there any secure erase softwares or techniques that someone could use to prevent any data recovery? Overwriting the data over and over again using the DoD 5220.22M technique has come with scrutiny over the years, is it effective for IOS devices (see imyfone Umate Pro)?

Comment: IOS really doesn't record all that much information. It's pretty much just configuration settings. It's not like NetFlow is enabled by default (NetFlow is sent over the network, not to local storage, typically). Also, using multiple overwrites will destroy the solid state storage which isn't meant for frequent writes.

Comment: https://community.cisco.com/t5/networking-documents/how-to-configure-logging-in-cisco-ios/ta-p/3132434 indicates that there is no logging to non-volatile storage.